# @Autowired doesn't work when using Jersey with Spring

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jax-rs

I am trying to use Jersey with Spring. But for the life of me, I can't figure out why my Spring dependencies aren't being injected into my Rest Class.

Each time I try and invoke the autowired dependency I get NULL. Can anyone suggest why my dependency isn't being injected?

My Rest Class looks like this:

```
com.myapp.rest

@Component
@Scope("request") 
@Path("/home")
public class ChartResource {

@Autowired
ChartService chartService;

@GET
@Path("/chart")
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
public Bean getChart() {
        return chartService.retrieveChart();


}
```

My web.xml file looks like this

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs;com.myapp.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>       
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>   
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

My applicationContext.xml is standard, and specifies the base package for component scanning:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<annotation-driven />
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp" />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Please post your applicationContext.xml file.  Typically it's the "standard" things that break stuff.  Also, please post the package of the rest class

Comment: Hi Chris, I've added the full applicationContext and package of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - silly question. My applicationContext wasn't being loaded and so it wasn't picking up the package I defined for component scanning!

Comment: You should mark this as the correct answer (by clicking on the hollow checkmark at the side of the answer) if it was truly the issue. It helps others searching for the same sort of issue by letting them know that yes, this really was the fix.

Comment: Can you clarify  My applicationContext wasn't being loaded

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

I'm not sure what you'll need to get Jersey's annotations to work, but `@Autowired` is a Spring annotation so you'll need to use the Spring version of `<annotation-config>` in order to get that to work properly.

Comment: Thanks Chris. As it happens I was being stupid and my applicationContext.xml wasn't being referenced properly in my web.xml. Fixing up the reference fixed it.